# To Exclude Refit.dll from Test project Code Coverage on Azure Devops pipeline builds

Tags: azure-devops, nunit, code-coverage, refit

I have Selenium based Automation project in .Net 6 that uses NUnit framework.
The CI/CD pipeline is configured in Azure Devops to run Code Coverage check and we see the Code Coverage results including the Refit.dll.

I want to exclude this refit.dll from the overall code coverage to improve the overall code coverage percent.

[image]

Please note as seen above ,I have referred  [Excluding files from code coverage analysis in Azure devops pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72616684/) to remove reference which worked for **NUnit3.TestAdapter.dll** but this does not work with **Refit.dll**

Comment: Not sure if you noticed, there were duplicate nodes of `<modulePaths>` and `<Exclude>` in the `.runsettings` contents that you shared. If using the exact format like in the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72616684/excluding-files-from-code-coverage-analysis-in-azure-devops-pipeline), will the issue be reproduced?

May I assume you were using `vstest` task and if you had eliminated the test assembly by `!**\*TestAdapter.dll`?

Comment: To isolate the cause of the issue by the differences in environments, could you run the command `dotnet test` command with `--settings` on your local machine to see if the issue persists in the generated report?